Remove invalid bytes, keep valid UTF-8 (in Ruby 2)
(I posted a similar problem here, but this new question is not a duplicate).
Using either Ruby 2.6.10 or 1.9.3 is a requirement that the software I'm developing here must run with these:
Small reproducible problem:
b = "L\xF6sé侍"

We have here a string, where one of its one bytes is illegal in UTF-8 (it's the byte with hex F6). The encoding of the String from the Ruby viewpoint is Encoding::UTF_8. Looking at the byte sequence, we can see
p b.bytes.to_a

=>
[76, 246, 115, 195, 169, 228, 190, 141]

My goal is to remove from the string all bytes which are illegal in UTF-8. I want to get in my simple example a string with content "Lsé侍".
I tried
c1 = b.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, replace: '')

but c1 has the same content as b. Then I tried
b.force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_UTF8)
c2 = b.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, replace: '')

but this also erases the characters é and 侍, since they are not valid in ASCII.
I also was thinking of putting together a hard coded list of those byte values which are invalid in UTF8, and simply delete them from the string, but this is ugly.
Any ideas how this can be done?
UPDATE: I published the code here based on my experiments in irb, but it turned out that irb seems to behave here a bit different from the non-interactive Ruby. You can find here a screenshot, which is based on the comment given by User @mate. To make it work, I couldn't assign the string in my JRuby program (this would have been rejected at compile time already), but read it from a file (which is what happens in our "real" application anyway).
Hence if you want to reproduce the example, download the file with the erroneous text from this download link and use the following Ruby script to run it:
p RUBY_VERSION
str = File.read("./errf.txt")
p str.bytes.to_a
str2 = str.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, replace: '')
p str2.bytes.to_a


b.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, replace: '') works for me (Ruby 3.3.0). It removes the byte 246.

@Dogbert: It was perhaps fixed in later Ruby versions. I'll update my post with my version.

I can confirm that String#encode method works on Ruby v. 2.2.4, at least with the provided string example. Check it out here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/14yy

Note: often it is better to substitute (with substitution character) and not remove: think about security implication (bypass some check and you remove and you may have unexpected strings)

There's no such thing as Encoding::ASCII_UTF8. Double-check your examples, please.

@Stefan: Thanks, fixed. I mistakingly copied the string from some other failed example.

@GiacomoCatenazzi : I know, but as a paid programmer, I have to implement, what the specification suggests, even if I don't like it.

@mate: The problem which I reported for MRI Ruby 2.6 was incorrectly reported. I was mislead by how /usr/bin/irb behaves on my Mac (irb - perhaps incorrectly - reports RUBY_VERSION as 2.6.10, and then, encode does erase the faulty chars). With /usr/bin/ruby your example indeed works, which means that the problem is reduced to the older Ruby I need to be compatible with. I have included now in my posting which basically contains your example, modified so that at least the String assignment works. You example would already abort compiling on my JRuby due to the illegal character in the string.

@Stefan: I do. I guess someone else wanted to edit it too.

Does this work for you? b.each_char.select(&:valid_encoding?).join()

@Fravadona : It does! Could you please post it as answer? Unless someone else comes up with a still better version, I will accept it!

You could split the string by "character", select the valid ones and re-join them into a string again:
"L\xF6sé侍".each_char.select(&:valid_encoding?).join()

"Lsé侍"


In Ruby 1.9, there was Iconv:
b = [76, 246, 115, 195, 169, 228, 190, 141].pack('c*').force_encoding('UTF-8')
#=> "L\xF6sé侍"

require 'iconv'

Iconv.conv('UTF-8//ignore','UTF-8', b)
#=> "Lsé侍"


Great approach. I did a small benchmark, to compare it with the version posted by @Fravadona, and to my surprise, his version was on my platform slightly (about 20%) faster, despite his need of creating a temporary array (and rejoining). Well, perhaps Iconf is doing something similar; I did not bother to study the library code. Being the speed advantage the only criterium I can think of, I will choose his answer as the accepted one.

The encode approach works fine with Ruby 2.6.10
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [arm64-darwin23]
$ ruby -e 'p "L\xF6sé侍".encode("UTF-8", invalid: :replace, replace: "")'
"Lsé侍"

